# Swift CryptoKit encryption yields inconsistent results

Tags: swift, encryption, apple-cryptokit

I have a simple encryption routine that produces different results each time it is executed. Can anyone identify the problem?  The code below just shows the same call three different times and as you can see the results are different on each call.

```
import SwiftUI
import CryptoKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var password = "TopSecret"
    @State var text = "My text"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Password", text: $password)
            TextField("Text", text: $text)
            Text(try! encrypt(password: password, text: text).hexEncodedString())
            Text(try! encrypt(password: password, text: text).hexEncodedString()).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            Text(try! encrypt(password: password, text: text).hexEncodedString())
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
func encrypt(password: String, text: String) throws -> Data {
    let x = [UInt8](text.utf8)
    return try encrypt(password: password, input: x)
}
```

---

```
func encrypt(password: String, input: [UInt8]) throws -> Data {
    let pwd = password.padding(toLength: 32, withPad: "@", startingAt: 0)
    let key = SymmetricKey(data: pwd.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    let sealedBox = try AES.GCM.seal(input, using: key)
    return sealedBox.combined!
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }
    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let format = options.contains(.upperCase) ? "%02hhX" : "%02hhx"
        return self.map { String(format: format, $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of secure encryption schemes such as the `seal` method. There is a random value (called the "nonce") included to ensure that every encryption is unique. All of these will decrypt properly.

If you require consiste nt (insecure) encryption results, for example in unit testing you can pass a static nonce value by passing a `nonce` parameter to `seal`.

Note that your key derivation is extremely insecure. You can't just pad an ASCII string into an AES key. It destroys the keyspace. For a computer-generated key, you should generate a random 32 bytes. For a human-generated password, you need a PBKDF (such as PBKDF2 or scrypt) to stretch the key. Unfortunately, I don't believe CryptoKit provides any tools to support password-based encryption; only random key encryption. You'll need to perform key stretching by hand using something like CommonCrypto or CryptoSwift, or you'll need to use a tool that supports passwords like Themis or RNCryptor.

Comment: AFAIR SymmetricKey random initializer supports  128, 192 or 256 bits

Comment: The random initializer of SymmetricKey will support any size. (But it's really only useful in protocols where you encrypt the SymmetricKey using a public key or shared secret. It's not really useful for the kind of problem the OP is describing.)

Comment: Yes I agree that its purpose is not for generating a key from a password. I just mentioned the size (16, 24 or 32 bytes)

Comment: Right; it has presets for those sizes, but you can pass any size you want.

Comment: yes that's the bitCount initializer of SymmetricKeySize but I would stick with 32 bytes (256 bits) as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Sajjon You should never use HKDF to derive a key from a password. It is only intended to derive a key from "keying material" (which is generally random data). Passwords provide too little entropy for HKDF to be effective. It provides insufficient stretching. (I'm not certain what Apple means by "passcode" in the HKDF docs, but it should not be the same thing as a password. It's possible they mean PIN, which is already so weak that I understand why maybe it doesn't really matter, but this is a very subtle point that can't be applied universally.)